# Filtering data with firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I want to filter some data with the firebase realtime database. First of all I want to check the IDs. The IDs are not allowed to be equal and if the IDs are not equal I want to check the price. For example all the products between 10$ and 20$.
I have already read that filtering data with firebase is hard to do. 
For any suggestions I am thankful, like alternative software to solve this problem. But it has to work with Android Studio.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has a lot of queries features that can help you.

Using startAt(), endAt(), and equalTo() allows you to choose arbitrary starting and ending points for your query.

Take a look at [this link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/11/firebase-now-with-more-querying.html) for more help